# Laravel - How to sort, order appended fields

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating a function to search books in specific genre. Everything works fine except sorting, ordering by 'stars' which is appended in model.

Function:

```
 $genre = Genre::find($genre_id);


    $phrase = $request->search;
    $sort = $request->sort;
    $order = $request['order'];


    if (!isset($sort) || !in_array($sort, ['title', 'stars', 'created_at', 'author_id']))
        $sort = 'title';

    if (!isset($order) || !in_array($order, ['DESC', 'ASC']))
        $order = 'DESC';


    $result['name'] = $genre->name;
    $result['results'] = Book::with('authors')->whereGenre_id($genre_id)->where('club_id', '=', $club_id)
        ->where(function ($query) use ($phrase, $club_id, $sort, $order, $user) {

            if (isset($phrase))
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $phrase . '%');
        })
        ->orderBy($sort, $order)
        ->get();
```

When I try to sort by 'stars' I get an error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'stars' in 'order clause' (SQL:
>   select * from `books` where `genre_id` = 1 and `club_id` = 24 and
>   `books`.`deleted_at` is null order by `stars` desc)

I understand this, stars doesn't exist in database, but how I can make this working?

Comment: Show Database structure & models

Comment: I think you should not `orderBy` with `$sort` because you say `stars' does not exist in database.

Comment: How is the star rating calculated? The downfall of sorting on a value that is appended, is that you will have to fetch *all* results from the database first, then append the calculated value and finally you will be able to sort it the way you want to sort it. With big result sets this approach is bound to become slow. Also you won't be able to paginate properly from the DB, you'll need to create a custom pagination based on a collection slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is final working code:

```
$res = Book::with('authors')
        ->where('genre_id', $genre_id)
        ->where('club_id', $club_id)
        ->where(function ($query) use ($phrase) {
            if (isset($phrase))
                $query->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $phrase . '%');
        })->get();

    if($order == 'ASC'){
        $res = $res->sortBy($sort);
    }else{
        $res = $res->sortByDesc($sort);
    }

    $result['results'] = $res->values()->all();
```

@mith I changed `->all()` to `->get()` and getting final result looks like this:

```
$result['results'] = $res->values()->all();
```

[Laravel documentation - sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sortby)